# Looping array from csv and update it to mongodb nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So i try to read a CSV file to JSON array using node js, and i try to update it to mongodb, is it possible way to looping the data and update it to database base on the JSON using this code, if its not possible is there a way to do it asynchronously using node, because i keep getting promise issue?
here is my code:

```
import csvtojson from "csvtojson";
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
const csvFilePath = "./data.csv";

console.log(" ");
const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

async function listDatabases(client) {
  const databasesList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases();

  console.log("Databases:");
  databasesList.databases.forEach((db) => console.log(` - ${db.name}`));
}

async function main() {
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  try {
    await client.connect();
    await listDatabases(client);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
main().catch(console.error);

async function updateData() {
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  const data = await csvtojson().fromFile(csvFilePath);
  console.log(data.length);
  data.map((datas) => {
    // console.log(datas);
    console.log(Object.keys(datas), Object.values(datas));
  });
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db("nabatiform");
    const stuff = db.collection("users");
    data.map((datas) => {
      // console.log(datas);
      console.log(Object.keys(datas), Object.values(datas));
const result = await stuff.findOneAndUpdate({})
    });
    
    
    console.log(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

updateData().catch(console.error);
```

here is my JSON that i read from CSV:

```
[{
    NIK: '22000028',
    Plant: 'Majalasgka',
    fullname: 'FERI FsaYAH',
    Group_Shift: 'R1',
    Gedung_Zona: 'Gas A',
    Sector: 'SEKTOas 08',
    SPV: 'TasI SUasWATI'
  },
  {
    NIK: '22000330',
    Plant: 'Majaaka',
    fullname: 'AYasdMAYANTI',
    Group_Shift: 'NSHT',
    Gedung_Zona: 'GEDU',
    Sector: 'SE-08',
    SPV: 'TI'
  },
]
```

here is what its look like on my document on mongodb:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6369b17b11e02557349d8de5"
  },
  "fullname": "EGA PERMANA SAPUTRA",
  "password": "$2b$10$TuKKwzIxmqvnJfR8LRV/zu1s.Gqpt4yANLAcNNFQ6pqTuLL82.00q",
  "NIK": "17000691",
  "status": "active",
  "department": "Prodaucasdfation",
  "position": "Foreasdman",
  "Group_Shift": "R1",
  "role": "user",
  "__v": 0,
  "createdAt": 1667871099,
  "updatedAt": 1669025651,
  "userInformation": {},
  "plant": "Majasangka"
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting `const result = await stuff.findOneAndUpdate({})` to do?

Comment: i mean is it possible to do it with that?

Comment: Are you trying to update documents or insert documents?  If there are any warning/error messages, you should show them in you question.

Comment: update document based on data from the JSON @rickhg12hs

Comment: Which field(s) identify the documents already in the collection that you want to update?

Comment: So, does `"NIK"` identify the specific document to be updated?

Comment: yep @rickhg12hs

Comment: data.map((datas) => {
      // console.log(datas);
      console.log(Object.keys(datas), Object.values(datas));
const result = await stuff.findOneAndUpdate({})
    });

use for loop instead of map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `forEach()` loop to push each `findOneAndUpdate()` function to an array. Then execute all the promises asynchronously using `Promise.all()`. This is much faster than using `await` inside a `map()` or `for` loop.

```js
async function updateData() {
  const promises = [];
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  const data = await csvtojson().fromFile(csvFilePath);
  console.log(data.length);
  data.map((datas) => {
    // console.log(datas);
    console.log(Object.keys(datas), Object.values(datas));
  });
  
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db("nabatiform");
    const stuff = db.collection("users");
    
    data.forEach((datas) => {
      console.log(Object.keys(datas), Object.values(datas));
      
      // Push each promise to array
      promises.push(stuff.findOneAndUpdate({}));     
    });
    
    // Execute all promises
    await Promise.all(promises);       
    
    console.log(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: `stuff.findOneAndUpdate({})`  Is there some kind of magic that provides the `filter` and `update` for `findOneAndUpdate`?  Or maybe I don't understand the API.

Answer (score 1):

use await while calling updateData()

```
await updateData().catch(console.error);
```

I whould suggest for loop instead of map because if you want yo use async and wait in the map it just won't work while for loop does not have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no javascript wizard, but hopefully this is helpful.

Perhaps a little modification of your `updateData` function will make the updates.  I don't really have a way to test it.

```js
async function updateData() {
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  const data = await csvtojson().fromFile(csvFilePath);
  console.log(data.length);
  data.map((datas) => {
    // console.log(datas);
    console.log(Object.keys(datas), Object.values(datas));
  });
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db("nabatiform");
    const stuff = db.collection("users");

    // Below here is what I modified.
    data.forEach(element => {
      const filter = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(element).filter(elem =>
        elem[0] == "NIK"
      ));
      const updateFields = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(element).filter(elem =>
        elem[0] != "NIK"
      ));
      const update = {$set: updateFields};
      const result = await stuff.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
    });   
    
    console.log(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}
```